# Concatenate Two Strings in HTML where one string has a Hyperlink in between

Tags: javascript, html, string

I have two strings in html. The two strings are "Forgotten your password?" and "Please" 'HPERLINK' "to change your password".

Now I have a messageBundle file which is a file to store constants. This file is used to translate the constants in other languages.
Now I have stored these strings in my constant file as:

```
Forgot_Pass="Forgotten your password?Please"
Forgot_password_continue="to change your password"
```

Then in html I am using this constants file to create a complete sentence on my UI as `"Forgotten your password? Please click_here to change your password"`.

Here 'click_here' is the hyperlink.
Is there anyway I can store this error message in a single string in my MessageBundle file so that concatenation of these 2 strings can be avoided?

Comment: To be honest, your question is unclear. I'd suggest you to please rephrase your question. May be even add some sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making use of a pre-defined pattern for variables (eg: ##1##, ##2## etc.,) that can be replaced with the corresponding values at the time of translation.

For example: You final (single) string could be as follows -

> Forgot_Pass_Change="Forgotten your password? Please ##1## to change
>   your password"

where **##1##** will need to be replaced with the **`<a href="http://your.link.path" >click_here</a>`** at the time of translation.

I understand that this means having to change the way the translation calls happen. Assuming that your current translation function is something like `getTranslatedString(<translate_string_name>)`, you could override it to something like the one shown below:

```
getTranslatedString('Forgot_Pass_Change', [<variable_1>, <variable_2> ...]);
```

i.e

```
getTranslatedString('Forgot_Pass_Change', ['click_here_hyperlink']);
```

In your example you have only 1 variable string. However, there will be cases where you will need to replace more than 1 variable at a time (denoted by **##2##**, **##3##** and so on, in your template string). Hence the array implementation as the second parameter.

Comment: How can we store the hyperlink in a constant in html so that we can pass this hyperlink as an argument to the mesaageBundle?

Comment: Is the messageBundle being read and used for translation in javascript (in the browser)? In any case, you may not need to store the hyperlink. Depending on your use-case, you might as well store it in a javascript variable and pass that variable to messageBundle.

Comment: Yes the messageBundle is being used for translation.But we are passing hyperlink from our javascript to this messageBundle as an argument.

Comment: Updated my answer to clear the confusion. Instead of 'click_here', the variable value will be the complete hyperlink (anchor tag). You might want to translate 'click_here' before embedding it as the anchor's text.

Comment: The translations are not in our hand , they are done by some other team.So we have to do everything on our end.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the solution for me:

```
Forgot_Pass="Forgotten your password?Please <a href="http://your/url/here">Click here</a> to change your password"
```

If I am wrong, please let me know.

Comment: This cannot be used by us as the messageBundle is just a constant file , it is not a html file .So I dont think it is feasible for us to do this.

Comment: @SurbhiMittal "This cannot be used by us as the messageBundle is just a constant file , it is not a html file " You can store HTML in a constant file, provided that the content is not dynamic. However, I do not see why should this content be dynamic in your case. You can store HTML into a .txt or whatever file, by the way.

Comment: We can only store constants in our messageBundle file as this file is used for translations.Whatever is written into this file gets translated into different languages.So if I include this tag in the messageBundle , then it will also get translated which we dont want.

Comment: What we were expecting is that this hyperlink that gets generated at run time is passed to this messageBundle as a constant and then we can use this file for translation.But doing all this at run time is not feasible we think.

Comment: Can we pass a html tag from my constant file to the javasciprt file?

Comment: @SurbhiMittal can't you turn off the translation for texts which contain characters like < or >? There should not be too many of these.

Comment: @SurbhiMittal probably you can, but I will need to know what you are trying to do. Explaining the exact process and code you have would improve a lot the quality of your question.

Comment: can't you turn off the translation for texts which contain characters like < or >? There should not be too many of these >> 
Thanks for this suggestion .It worked :)

Comment: @SurbhiMittal you can exclude the parts between < and > from the string to be translated and put it back. You could use the translator without those parts. If this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the corrects answer.